# Can't see crashlytics issues

Tags: swift, firebase, crashlytics

As is shown in the screenshot; crashlytics detects the crash but not showing the issue.

[image]

Both pods are installed

```
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

`"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` is in New Run Script Phase

`DWARF with dSYM File` is selected in the Debug information

Finally tried the crash sample method and as shown in the screenshot it works but can't see the issue itself. Am I missing anything?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric/Firebaser here -

When testing your Crashlytics setup on the simulator, there are a few steps you should take to ensure that Crashlytics can upload the crash report, because Xcode's debugger will attach itself at app launch by default otherwise:

1. Run your app from Xcode to install it on the simulator or your device
2. Press the Stop button in Xcode to quit it
3. Launch your app from the home screen to run it without the debugger
4. Press the “Crash” button to trigger the crash
5. Run the app again from Xcode so it can deliver the recorded crash to Crashlytics

Taken from "Code examples" [here](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features).

Answer (score 0):

I was testing on the simulator. When I tested the app on my device the issues are shown now.